# Unity AR: How to get Script Component from an Prefab that gets instantiated during play?

Tags: unity-game-engine, components, augmented-reality

I want to reference a Component that gets instantiated during playtime and not before. I have a game object called `GroundPlacement` has this script `ARTapToPlaceObjects` attached to it. This script places the ground in the play environment during runtime. The `objectToPlace` variable holds the `ground prefab` which has a `Spawner` script attached in its child and `placedObject` is the actual instantiated ground that is placed during the game.

Now, I have multiple other scripts and I want to access the functionality of the `Spawner` script but I don't know how to rightly get the component. How I wrote the code now throws an NullException.

Console output:

```
piece removed from list: False
spawned pieces: 0
Spawner:RemovePieceFromSpawnedList(GamePiece)
Spawner:RemoveAllGamePiecesOnGround()
ARTapToPlaceObjects:ResetGround()
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.UI.InputSystemUIInputModule:ProcessPointerButton(ButtonState&, PointerEventData)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.UI.InputSystemUIInputModule:ProcessPointer(PointerModel&)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.UI.InputSystemUIInputModule:Process()
```

[image: GroundPlacementInEditor]
[image: GroundPrefab]
[image: GroundPrefabChild]

Some code from the `ARTapToPlaceObjects` script:

```
  public class ARTapToPlaceObjects : MonoBehaviour
  {

    private Spawner spawnerRef;        

    private void Awake()
    {
          gameManager = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
          spawnerRef = FindObjectOfType<Spawner>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdatePlacementPose();
        UpdatePlacementIndicator();

        PlaceGround();
    }

    private void PlaceGround()
    {
        if(!groundIsSet)
        {
            if (placementPoseIsValid && Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                objectToPlace.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(placementIndicator.transform.position, placementIndicator.transform.rotation);
                placedObject = Instantiate(objectToPlace, placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);

                //set the ground only once
                groundIsSet = true;

                //setting variables related to current placedObject
                spawnerRef = placedObject.GetComponentInChildren<Spawner>();
                placedObjectDimMin = placedObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshCollider>().bounds.min;
                placedObjectDimMax = placedObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshCollider>().bounds.max;
                placedObjectRotation = placedObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshCollider>().transform.rotation;

                //Debug.Log($"placedObject.Transform: {placedObject.transform.position}");
                //Debug.Log($"Placed\n dimBoundsSize: {groundDimensions}\n dimMin: {placedObjectDimMin}\n dimMax: {placedObjectDimMax}\n dimRot: {placedObjectRotation.ToString()}");
            }
        }
    }

    public void ResetGround()
    {
        //remove all spawned game pieces
        spawnerRef.RemoveAllGamePiecesOnGround();
        Debug.Log("removed all current game pieces: " + spawnerRef.spawnedPieces.Count == null);

        //remove current ground
        Destroy(placedObject.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("removed current ground: " + placedObject == null);
        
        //reset ground
        groundIsSet = false;
        PlaceGround();
    }
}
```

The ground prefab has the `Spawner` Script attached to it (in its child object). Some code snippets:

```
  public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public GamePiece[] gamePieces; //prefab list
      public List<GamePiece> spawnedPieces; //spawned pieces in the game

      public void RemoveAllGamePiecesOnGround()
      {
          for(int x = 0; x < spawnedPieces.Count; x++)
          {
              Destroy(spawnedPieces[x]);
              RemovePieceFromSpawnedList(spawnedPieces[x]);
          }
          Debug.Log("spawned pieces count is now: " + spawnedPieces.Count);
      }

      public void AddPieceToSpawnedList(GamePiece piece)
      {
          spawnedPieces.Add(piece);
          Debug.Log("piece added to list: " + ", spawned pieces count is now: " + spawnedPieces.Count);
      }
  }
```

The `GamePiece` script (attached to the game piece prefabs that get spawned during play) wants to access `Spawner` as well and I tried to reference the component through another way. But this doesnt work either. For example and this function does not get executed (Debug.Line not printing, so the problem must lie in spawnerRef.)

```
public class GamePiece : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Spawner spawnObjectsRef;

    private void Awake()
    {
        collider = GetComponentInChildren<BoxCollider>();
        spawnObjectsRef = groundPlacementRef.PlacedObject.GetComponentInChildren<Spawner>();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        spawnObjectsRef.RemovePieceFromSpawnedList(this);

        Debug.Log("object clicked, now destroying");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

In the same session I get this error:

```
    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at GamePiece.Awake () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Object.Internal_InstantiateSingle (UnityEngine.Object data, UnityEngine.Vector3 pos, UnityEngine.Quaternion rot) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Spawner+<SpawnRandomGamePieces>d__25.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
UnityEngine.Object:Internal_InstantiateSingle(Object, Vector3, Quaternion)
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(Object, Vector3, Quaternion)
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(T, Vector3, Quaternion)
<SpawnRandomGamePieces>d__25:MoveNext()
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A prefab doesnt exist yet.  I skimmed the code didn't see you instantiate it. Where you do you can keep a reference to it. Then get a component from the instantiated gameobject etc

Comment: The prefab exists after making the ground placement. Meaning it doesn't exist at the start of the game only after some action of the player. That is why I am not sure how to reference it. You are right I didn't include for the instantiation. I added that.

Comment: Well. wherever you instantiate it.  Keep a reference to it.